# How to setup wireless networking with my USB WiFi adapter?

Tags: networking, wifi, usb

I've bought and plugged in a USB WiFi adapter, a [UGreen AC650](https://www.ugreen.com/products/ac650-dual-banc-usb-wlan-adapter). It's supposed to support Linux 5.x...

well, lsusb says:

```
Bus 001 Device 038: ID 0bda:c811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC
```

So it is recognized to some extent. However, it doesn't show up with `ip link show`.

I've run the [`wireless-info-script`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180), and the results are [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/p9GzStSx); but note that my system has another wifi adapter, on-board, which is working fine (but unused); and an active Ethernet connection, so don't mistake those (`eth0`, `wlan0`) for the missing USB WiFi adapter.

My question: Can I get the USB WiFi adapter fully recognized and configured? If so, how?

I'd rather use the command line for this. I'll mention that for quite a few years I had grown accustomed to wi-fi networking "just working", and no longer quite remember what to do with `ip`, `iwlist` and friends. (I do have the cinnamon network manager on, but later I plan to use this adapter on other machines which won't have that.)

I should also mention that this USB dongle has what appears to be an indicator light - but it doesn't light up.

---

tail of `/var/log/messages`:

```
Mar 20 09:25:27 myhostname kernel: [292007.468991] usb 1-9: new high-speed USB device number 48 using xhci_hcd
Mar 20 09:25:27 myhostname kernel: [292007.617381] usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=c811, bcdDevice= 2.00
Mar 20 09:25:27 myhostname kernel: [292007.617387] usb 1-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Mar 20 09:25:27 myhostname kernel: [292007.617391] usb 1-9: Product: 802.11ac NIC
Mar 20 09:25:27 myhostname kernel: [292007.617394] usb 1-9: Manufacturer: Realtek
Mar 20 09:25:27 myhostname kernel: [292007.617396] usb 1-9: SerialNumber: 123456
Mar 20 09:25:27 myhostname mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 48: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9"
Mar 20 09:25:27 myhostname mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 48 was not an MTP device
Mar 20 09:25:27 myhostname mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 48: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9"
Mar 20 09:25:27 myhostname mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 48 was not an MTP device
```

tail of `dmesg`:

```
Mar20 09:25] usb 1-9: new high-speed USB device number 48 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.148390] usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=c811, bcdDevice= 2.00
[  +0.000006] usb 1-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  +0.000004] usb 1-9: Product: 802.11ac NIC
[  +0.000003] usb 1-9: Manufacturer: Realtek
[  +0.000002] usb 1-9: SerialNumber: 123456
```

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180 I know it's an Ubuntu answer, but the information collection should work for you.

Comment: @waltinator: See edit and link to the collected info.

Comment: Can you `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you plug it in? Or use `sudo /bin/ls -t /var/log/` and `less` the most recently modified logfile just after plugging it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The USB vendor ID `0bda` and product ID `c811` would seem to indicate the WiFi chip in the new adapter is a Realtek RTL8811CU. These IDs should be readable in a standard way from every USB device in existence, so the ability to see them proves nothing at all about driver support.

Unfortunately, the support for this chip is not yet included in the standard kernel, so you'll need to build a third-party driver, for example from here:

https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU (a driver for both RTL8811CU and RTL8821CU)

https://github.com/morrownr/8821cu-20210118 (a driver for RTL8811CU, RTL8821CU and RTL8731AU; seems to be more recently updated)

Comment: That is quite unfortunate ... since I was hoping to plug this thing in to existing PCs and have it just work. Do you know when this driver is planned to go into the standard kernel? ... anyway, +1.

Comment: This worked for me. The only downside is an overly long interface name... :-P